# How to create TRIGGER who will be save the schemat change

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, audit

I am new on forum. I am sorry from my English.

My question is: How to create a TRIGGER which will save any change on a DB.

For example (Add column, create table, drop database, replace function ).

I want to save this information in a table. I want to save information about all tables(rows) and function in DATABASE;

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createeventtrigger.html But there is no way you can catch a `drop database` as the trigger which could record that will be deleted together with the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### My answer is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audyt_abort_any_command()
  RETURNS event_trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
  AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO audit_query (user_change, date_change, tg_tag, query) 
                    VALUES ( user, now(), tg_tag, current_query());
END;
$$;

CREATE TABLE audit_query (
    id serial,
    user_change        varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    date_change timestamp,
    tg_tag       varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    query    text NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER save_audit_ddl ON ddl_command_start
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE audyt_abort_any_command();
```